# pthread c++ invalid conversation from void * (*) to void* (*)(void*)

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm new in `C++` and trying to create multiple threads with `pthread`.

```
typedef struct thread_args{
    int &sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in &serv_addr;
    int size_serv_addr;
    socklen_t &clilen;
    int &newsockfd;
};

void create_server(int &sockfd, struct sockaddr_in &serv_addr, int size_serv_addr, socklen_t &clilen, int &newsockfd){
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int sockfd, newsockfd;
     socklen_t clilen;

     pthread_t t1;
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
     struct thread_args *args;
     args->clilen = clilen;
     args->newsockfd = newsockfd;
     args->serv_addr = serv_addr;
     args->size_serv_addr = sizeof(serv_addr);
     args->sockfd = sockfd;


     pthread_create(&t1, NULL, create_server, &args);
     printf("hello abc");
     return 0; 
}
```

When I run this code, it has a message:

```
error:/bin/sh -c 'make -j 4 -e -f   error: invalid conversion from 'void* (*)(int&, sockaddr_in&, int, socklen_t&, int&) {aka void* (*)(int&, sockaddr_in&, int, unsigned int&, int&)}' to 'void* (*)(void*)' [-fpermissive]
      pthread_create(&t1, NULL, create_server, &args);
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you have C++11 why not use `std::thread`?  It actually uses the type system instead of casting everywhere.

Comment: The only type of function you can send to `pthread_create` are the ones with prototype `void* create_server(void*)`. You need to change your `create_server` function or better us `std::thread` as mentioned by NathanOliver.

Comment: @NathanOliver Reminds me of the old joke "to a C programmer, strong typing is when he's angry at his keyboard." :)

Comment: @erip Never heard that one.  That was great.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm trying to create multiple threads, `std::thread` can only run one thread `.join()`

Comment: @Mr2uang that is not true. You can have a vector of threads / pointer to threads

Comment: @Mr2uang As Hayt said you can have a container of threads.

Comment: @Mr2uang [Here](http://progsch.net/wordpress/?p=81)'s how to create a basic threadpool in C++11

Comment: Echoing what the others have said. Please please please use standard facilities when possible (e.g. now!). There is no need for the platform-specific, C-like code shown here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signature for your thread function should be:

```
void *(*start_routine) (void *)
```

but you provide:

```
void create_server(int &sockfd, struct sockaddr_in &serv_addr, int size_serv_addr, socklen_t &clilen, int &newsockfd)
```

you should create a function like:

```
void* myThread(void *arg);
```

then `args` argument in `pthread_create` call will be passed as `arg` parameter to `myThread`, you can use its fields to call `create_server`

Comment: You mean I should create function like this [paste.ubuntu](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23251118/)

Comment: @Mr2uang yes, also consider calling `pthread_join` on your thread before main ends.

Comment: I followed like you said: the result is segment faults

Comment: @Mr2uang look at this line: `struct thread_args *args;` it is not initialized pointer, you need to allocate it : `thread_args *args = new thread_args;`

Comment: another thing: in your `thread_args` you have reference variables, why you need them? Remove all the `&` from this struct.

Comment: and final hint, your use of join is wrong, it should look as follows `pthread_t th = pthread_create(&t1, NULL, mythread, &args); pthread_join(th, NULL);`

Answer (score 0):

Your function definition does not match the type pthread_create wants to have. It requires only 1 arguments and that is a `void*` (so a function `void function(void* args)`).

you need to change `create_server` to

```
void create_server(void* voidArgs) {
    thread_args* args = static_cast<thread_args*>(voidArgs);
    //...
}
```

You will not have those issues though if you use the c++11 std::thread object. There you can directly use the argument type and with any number of arguments you like. So you don't have to define the thread_args struct.

Comment: @Mr2uang a std::thread is an object. If you want 2 threads you can instantiate 2 thread objects.

Comment: I already tried `std::thread` before. when I start `std::thread` by `.join()`, it must finish to run next step in `main()`.

Comment: @Mr2uang What you do is create all of the threads.  Then as the last thing you do before `main` exits is you call `join` on all of them.

Comment: @Mr2uang the threads will be started when you create the object. There is no need to call `join` to start them. You need to call join though before they get destroyed to wait for them to finish and release resources.

Comment: @Hayt Thanks for helping me understand how thread work in `c++`, not like `Java` you need to run `.start()`.